# How to configure sonarqube with TFS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, sonarqube

I want to configure sonarqube for my project in TFS 2012.As the prescript postscript options are not available while creating new build definition in build templates. Is it possible to configure sonarqube on TFS 2012 without upgrade to 2013 or 2015.Thanks in advance.

Comment: TFS 2012 isn't officially supported - so all solutions that you might find will be just hacks.

Comment: Thanks for your update.